# Primfaces 6.2 with Serenity (Datatable issue)

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, xhtml

### Heading ##We are using Primefaces 6.2 with JSF2.1.0 .

our datatable definition is as follows in the xhtml.

```html
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="datatable" style="min-height:450px !important;"
             widgetVar="searchDataTable" resizableColumns="false" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
             styleClass="ui-datatable-ver-scroll datatable-wrap-column" 
             filteredValue="#{advSearchAction.filteredSearchList}"
             value="#advSearchAction.searchValueBeanLazyDataModel}" paginator="true" 
             rowKey="#{datatable.ROWID}" filterEvent="change" rows="#{sessionScope['SRGRID_ROWS']}"
             lazy="true" selection="#{advSearchAction.selectedRecordArr}" 
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="# {commonmsg.searchDataTable$rowsPerPageTemplate}" 
             paginatorPosition="bottom">
```

Here the datas are all getting populated successfully in the datatable and if we choose the datarow then it is throwing null pointer exception.

**See the error below.**

> 15:15:10,441 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-85-2) java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.iii.orn11j.advsearch.SearchValueBeanLazyDataModel.getRowData(SearchValueBeanLazyDataModel.java:67) [classes:]
>       at com.iii.orn11j.advsearch.SearchValueBeanLazyDataModel.getRowData(SearchValueBeanLazyDataModel.java:1) [classes:]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:1445) [primefaces-6.2.jar:]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeSingleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:75) [classes:]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:57) [classes:]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-6.2.jar:]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]

My **SearchValueLazyBeanDataModel** method call is as below

```
@Override
public SearchValueBean getRowData(String rowKey) {
    final List<SearchValueBean> rows = (List<SearchValueBean>)getWrappedData();

    for (SearchValueBean SearchValueBean : rows) {
        if (SearchValueBean.getROWID().equals(rowKey))
            return SearchValueBean;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here the rowid passed from the xhtml is coming and during the decodeSingleSelection() method of SelectionFeature class, the `getRowData()` method of datatable returns null and NullPointerException is thrown from the calling part.

Note : we have customized the SelectionFeature.java of primefaces jar and 
below is the error part of my code when we debug.

```
void decodeSingleSelection(DataTable table, String selection) {
    if (ComponentUtils.isValueBlank(selection)) {
        table.setSelection(null);
    } else {
        table.setSelection(table.getRowData(selection));
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Comment: So if you don't use serenity it works? And it works with PF 6.1 or 7.0RC1?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. And the error is trown in a method in a class that you say you customized but you don't show that code? And did you debug exactly where the 'null' is returned that results in the NPE? Please narrow down the cause and improve the code in the question. Otherwise it is next to impossible to help

Comment: Yes . Its working fine with out serenity.

Comment: So you debugged the requests from the client to the server with and without serenity and did not notice any differences? AND What is null? Narrow that down

Comment: No differences I found .. But the table.getRowData(selection) returns null value and seems there is no data available in the Datatable ..

Comment: Then try to find where it is set (an IDE would be able to find references), set a breakpoint and see if it is not set when using serenity but is set when not using it... debug...

Comment: In the screen , I can see the datas available in the datatable . but when comes to the SelectionFeature, It is loosing the datas..The same is working in 5.2 without serenity

Comment: this is debugged using IDE (Eclipse)

Comment: Then check/debug what sets it to null... And where... And display is a different action then submitting... And 5.2 without serenity? What about 6.2 without serenity

Comment: And again... [mcve] please.... Also read http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: And when in doubt if you truly feel its a Serenity problem ask on the Serenity forum: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewforum.php?f=73

Comment: By removing serenity jar also having the same problem. so no need to communicate serentiy forum. Thanks